# SQL Oracle - Multiprocessor Scheduling: Greedy Number Partitioning

Tags: sql, oracle, greedy, analytic-functions, hierarchical-query

Is there an SQL statement to perform greedy number partitioning? (Oracle 19c)

I want to divide jobs among N processors.

Example,

Given the following workload data set:

```sql
job
---
4
60
50
1
100
6
```

Expected result set (assuming just N=2 where ties go to the processor with the fewest number of jobs assigned to it):

```sql
job  processor
---  ---------
100  1
 60  2
 50  2
  6  1
  4  1
  1  2
```

The following table may help clarify how those processors were assigned.

```sql
job  processor  length  count
---  ---------  ------  -----
100  1          100     1
 60  2           60     1
 50  2          110     2
  6  1          106     2
  4  1          110     3
  1  2          111     3
```

Some combination of analytic functions and hierarchical queries seems like it could make this happen without having to resort to procedural code.  Thanks in advance for your thoughts and assistance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a recursive CTE:

```
with tt as (
      select job, row_number() over (order by job desc) as seqnum
      from t
     ),
     cte(job, seqnum, processor, proc1, proc2, lev) as (
      select job, seqnum, 1, job as proc1, 0 as proc2, 1
      from tt
      where seqnum = 1
      union all
      select tt.job, tt.seqnum,
             (case when cte.proc1 > cte.proc2 then 2 else 1 end),
             (case when cte.proc1 > cte.proc2 then cte.proc1 else cte.proc1 + tt.job end),
             (case when cte.proc1 > cte.proc2 then cte.proc2 + tt.job else cte.proc2 end),
             lev + 1
      from cte join
           tt
           on tt.seqnum = cte.seqnum + 1
     )
select *
from cte
order by seqnum;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=9488cc423040c09a0f4dae8fb52d50a8) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: Wow, thanks.  Was not even aware of the recursive variety of CTEs.  How to generalize this to N number of processors?  Using the above template, thinking dynamic SQL would be required to generate the cte with proc1, proc2, ..., procN and the case conditions.  Perhaps there is a way that is a cleaner generalization than dynamic SQL?

Comment: @AlexBartsmon . . . If you know the number of processors, you would have additional columns for each processor.  I would note that this answers the question that you asked here.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a pipelined function using the types:

```sql
CREATE TYPE job_processor AS OBJECT(
  job       NUMBER,
  processor NUMBER
);

CREATE TYPE job_processor_list AS TABLE OF job_processor;
```

Then the function is:

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION partition_jobs (
  num_processors IN PLS_INTEGER
) RETURN job_processor_list PIPELINED
IS
  processor_time     SYS.ODCINUMBERLIST := SYS.ODCINUMBERLIST();
  processor_id       PLS_INTEGER;
  min_processor_time TABLE_NAME.JOB%TYPE;
BEGIN
  processor_time.EXTEND( num_processors );

  FOR i IN 1 .. num_processors LOOP
    processor_time(i) := 0;
  END LOOP;

  FOR j IN ( SELECT job FROM table_name ORDER BY job DESC ) LOOP
    processor_id       := 1;
    min_processor_time := processor_time( processor_id );
    
    FOR i IN 2 .. num_processors LOOP
      IF processor_time(i) < min_processor_time THEN
        processor_id       := i;
        min_processor_time := processor_time( processor_id );
      END IF;
    END LOOP;
    
    PIPE ROW ( job_processor( j.job, processor_id ) );
    processor_time( processor_id ) := processor_time( processor_id ) + j.job;
  END LOOP;
END;
/
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE TABLE_NAME ( job ) AS
SELECT   4 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT  60 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT  50 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT   1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 100 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT   6 FROM DUAL;
```

Then:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   TABLE( partition_jobs( 2 ) );
```

Outputs:

> ```
> JOB | PROCESSOR
> --: | --------:
> 100 |         1
>  60 |         2
>  50 |         2
>   6 |         1
>   4 |         1
>   1 |         1
> ```

and:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   TABLE( partition_jobs( 3 ) );
```

Outputs:

> ```
> JOB | PROCESSOR
> --: | --------:
> 100 |         1
>  60 |         2
>  50 |         3
>   6 |         3
>   4 |         3
>   1 |         2
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=6c270d4d60fc3988b9f8dba8f2cb8230)*